# How to convert pubDate from rss feed when importing using DIH in Solr?

Tags: solr, dih, pubdate

I am using RSS DIH in solr to index various rss feeds. The issue I am facing is in date field. The pubDate return in RSS is not in the format Solr expects and hence I get the exception when I start my Solr with this rss-data-config.xml file. Can someone tell me how I can convert the rss date into solr expected date format in rss-data-config.xml file?

In Schema.xml I have defined pubDate as date.

here is how my rss-data-config.xml looks:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="URLDataSource" name="dsurl"/>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="dsdb" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HCDACoreDB" user="root" password="CDA@318"/>
    <document>
        <entity name="rssimports"
                pk="link"
                url="${dataimporter.request.feedurl}"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                forEach="/rss | /rss/channel | /rss/channel/item"
                transformer="HTMLStripTransformer"
                dataSource="dsurl">

            <field column="source" xpath="/rss/channel/title" commonField="true" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="source-link" xpath="/rss/channel/link" commonField="true" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="Source-desc" xpath="/rss/channel/description" commonField="true" dataSource="dsurl"/>

            <field column="title" xpath="/rss/channel/item/title" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="link" xpath="/rss/channel/item/link" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="description" xpath="/rss/channel/item/description" stripHTML="true" dataSource="dsurl"/>
        <field column="pubDate" xpath="/rss/channel/item/pubDate" dataSource="dsurl"/>

            <field column='${dataimporter.functions.formatDate('${dataimporter.request.pubDate}', 'EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z')}' name="pubDate"/>
            <field column="guid" xpath="/rss/channel/item/guid" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="content" xpath="/rss/channel/item/content" dataSource="dsurl"/>
            <field column="author" xpath="/rss/channel/item/creator" dataSource="dsurl"/>


        <entity name="feedcategory" 
                query="select category.CategoryName from feeds, category where feeds.FeedUrl = '${dataimporter.request.feedurl}' AND feeds.FeedCategory = category.CategoryId"
                processor="SqlEntityProcessor" 
                dataSource="dsdb">
            <field column="CategoryName" name="category" dataSource="dsdb"/>
        </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 2):

You want to set up the DateFormatTransformer to deal with getting the date to the format solr is expecting.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer

Comment: Thank you, it resolved the exception I was getting and was able to index the doc. I will check now if NOW or NOW-1DAY type of filtering on pubDate works, thats what i wanted to do. Thank you again.

Comment: oops tried the following in format <field column="pubDate" xpath="/rss/channel/item/pubDate" dateTimeFormat="EEE, d MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z" dataSource="dsurl"/> and the exception I am getting is: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=http://rss.cnn.com/~r/rss/cnn_allpolitics/~3/R2L1CPDPBJU/] Error adding field
'pubDate'='Wed, 15 Aug 2012 14:11:27 EDT' WHat might be the problem?